# Are Scriptable Objects linked to a Prefab only instantiated once?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have three prefabs:

[image: three prefabs]

All three the prefabs have a Scriptable Object linked like this:

[image: prefab 1 with scriptable object]

[image: prefab 2 with scriptable object]

[image: prefab 3 with scriptable object]

The Linked Scriptable Object of all three prefabs is of type `SO_Item` Scriptable Object which looks like:

```
using UnityEngine;

[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "so_Item", menuName = "Scriptable Objects/Item/Item")]
public class SO_Item : ScriptableObject
{
    [field: SerializeField] public ItemDetails ItemDetails { get; set; }
}
```

Now my question is those three prefabs, I use in my scene like:

[image: Prefabs/Items used in scene]

Does this instantiate for every item in my scene a new instance of the linked Scriptable Objects?

Comment: No, ScriptableObjects won't be cloned unless you explictly call `Object.Instantiate`.

Answer (score 1):

Nope!

They will all share the same `ScriptableObject` instance and hence also share the same `ItemDetails` instance.

---

If you rather want a copy you can initially use e.g.

```
[SerializeField] private SO_Item soItem;

private SO_Item runtimeSOItem;

private void Awake ()
{
    runtimeSOItem = Instantiate(soItem);
}
```

which will create a new detached individual instance of the `ScriptableObject`.